# Oracle/PLSql Iterate table and index a column

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I have a table like this

```
section_id
=========
   1A
   1A
   1B 
   1B
   1B
   1C
```

and I need to create a numeric column with the index of every element group, like this:

```
 index  section_id
======  =========
    1       1A
    2       1A
    1       1B 
    2       1B
    3       1B
    1       1C
```

How can I do this in an Oracle Database?

Comment: `SELECT section_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by section_id order by section_id) AS index FROM your_tab ORDER BY index, section_id`

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but i think that the best solution is to order the partiion on the rownum to mantain the correct rows order.

Comment: `rownum` is dynamically created based on the query results. It is not the order the rows were inserted. If you need the insertion order, you need to add a column to track that.

Answer (score 0):

The [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) window function is your friend. Note, BTW, that `index` is a reserved word, and you may want to consider a different name. Anyway:

```
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY section_id ORDER BY 1), session_id
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` function:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0dcbf/1/0)**

```
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY section_id ORDER BY section_id) AS "index"
   ,section_id
FROM tab
ORDER BY section_id, "index";
```